# Ansible runs all dependency role even specifying specific tags

Tags: ansible

Ansible executes all dependency role but my main.yml in meta folder looks like this:

```
---
dependencies:
   - { role: common, caller_role: docker, tags: ['packages'] }
```

So, ansible should execute that part of role common that contains the following:

```
---

- name: Install required packages
  package: name={{ item.name }} state=present
  with_items:
    - "{{ vars[caller_role]['SYSTEM']['PACKAGES'] }}"
  tags:
    - packages

- name: Modify /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    line: "{{ vars[caller_role]['REGISTRY']['ip'] }} {{ vars[caller_role]['REGISTRY']['hostname']}}"
  tags:
    - write_etc_hosts
```

I execute ansible 2.1.1.0 as follows: ansible-playbook --list-tags site.yml and here i'm copying site.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  roles:
    - docker
```

And finally the tree:

```
├── common
│   ├── defaults
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── files
│   ├── handlers
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── meta
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── tasks
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── inventory
│   │   └── test.yml
│   └── vars
│       └── main.yml
├── docker
│   ├── defaults
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── files
│   ├── handlers
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── meta
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── tasks
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── inventory
│   │   └── test.yml
│   └── vars
│       └── main.yml
└── site.yml
```

I fail to understand what is happening..

Answer (score 3):

If you specify tags for a role, Ansible applies them to **every task** in that role.
In your example, tag `packages` will be added to every task in the role `common`.

Please inspect [tag inheritance](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance) section in the documentation.

> You can apply tags to more than tasks, but they ONLY affect the tasks themselves. Applying tags anywhere else is just a convenience *so you don’t have to write it on every task*
>
> All of these [samples] apply the specified tags to EACH task inside the play, included file, or role, so that these tasks can be selectively run when the playbook is invoked with the corresponding tags.

Answer (score -1):

OK, thank you Konstantin. For this purpose i think i will use:

```
- include: foo.yml
  tags: [web,foo]
```

Regards

Comment: This will still append `web` and `foo` tags to every task in `foo.yml`...